# Is there a way to edit a UDF disk image file/ISO image?

Tags: mount, iso, disk-image, udf

I have an ISO image with a UDF filesystem and a boot sector and I need to add a file to it. When I do

```
sudo mount -o loop,rw /tmp/file.iso /tmp/dir
```

I get

```
mount: block device /tmp/file.iso is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

This happens even if I remove `loop` or add `unhide`. The file has permissions `rw-rw-rw-`. I have tried various UDF command-line tools, but they all demand an actual CD drive, and won't even work with the loopback device. So is there anything I can do?

Because this has a boot sector, I'd rather edit the ISO file directly than unpack/repack.

Using Kubuntu 14.04 here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to browse, add and delete files in an ISO file without unpacking/repacking it by simply opening it with the Archive Manager (Ubuntu 14.04).

Hopefully you can do the same using Kubuntu.

Comment: Archive Manager is file-roller, right? Or has that changed?

Comment: Yes that's it, Archive Manager is its new name (like Files for Nautilus...).

Comment: It does not seem to be reading the UDF section of the disk image. All I see is a single folder `.` with nothing inside. This is both with the package and with  a file-roller master build via jhbuild.

Comment: For UDF images I only see a `README.TXT` saying 
"This disc contains a "UDF" file system and requires an operating system
that supports the ISO-13346 "UDF" file system specification.".

Answer (score -1):

What you've done is somewhat correct, but you must login as a root user.

```
sudo su -
```

Create a mount point:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/<mount_name>
```

The use mount command as follows to mount ISO file .iso:

```
mount -o loop disk1.iso /mnt/<mount_name>
```

Change directory to list files stored inside an ISO image:

```
cd /mnt/<mount_name>
ls -l
```

Comment: I did use sudo; the output of my original question was with sudo. Edited.

Comment: See changes in my answer, try that, and please let me know.

Comment: Still complains about write-protect.

Comment: @Mitch Your `mount -o loop` command says :

`mount: block device /tmp/toto.iso is write-protected, mounting read-only`

Comment: @SebMa Just to clarify, you did use `sudo` right?

Comment: @Mitch I tried both methods : with `sudo su -` then `mount -o loop` and I tried with `sudo mount -o loop`. Both methods said : `mount: block device /tmp/toto.iso is write-protected, mounting read-only`

Comment: Try to install smbfs. `sudo apt install smbfs`, and then try that.

Comment: This answer is plain wrong and weird. Iso9660 ain't really made to be editable. And the suggestion to install smbfs makes it even weirder. Smbfs is a network file system from Microsoft, and doesn't even make sense for physical disks.